# Android Kotlin how to save state of recyclerview with checkbox on screen rotation?

Tags: android, kotlin, android-recyclerview

```
class MainActivity : AppCompatActivity() {

    val groceryList = ArrayList<String>()
    var recyclerViewGroceryList : RecyclerView ?= null
    lateinit var adapter: recyclerviewadapter

    override fun onCreate(savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState)
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main)
        groceryList.add("data")
        groceryList.add("data")
        groceryList.add("data")
        groceryList.add("data")

        adapter = recyclerviewadapter(groceryList)
    
        recyclerViewGroceryList = findViewById(R.id.recyclerViewGroceryList)
        recyclerViewGroceryList?.layoutManager = LinearLayoutManager(this)
        recyclerViewGroceryList?.adapter = adapter
    }
}
```

Thats my main method. Here is my adapter class.

```
class recyclerviewadapter(private val list: ArrayList<String>) :
    RecyclerView.Adapter<recyclerviewadapter.ViewHolder>() {

    class ViewHolder(view: View) : RecyclerView.ViewHolder(view) {
        var checkBox = view.findViewById<CheckBox>(R.id.groceryListCheckBox)
        var groceryText = view.findViewById<TextView>(R.id.groceryListTextView)
    }

    override fun onCreateViewHolder(viewGroup: ViewGroup, viewType: Int): ViewHolder {
        val view = LayoutInflater.from(viewGroup.context)
            .inflate(R.layout.recyclerviewitem, viewGroup, false)
        return ViewHolder(view)
    }

    override fun onBindViewHolder(viewHolder: ViewHolder, position: Int) {
        var data_position = list.get(position)
        viewHolder.groceryText.text = "$data_position"
    }

    override fun getItemCount() = list.size
}
```

This is the XML file for the item in the recyclerview.

```
<androidx.cardview.widget.CardView xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content" >

    <androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent">

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/groceryListTextView"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_marginStart="20dp"
            android:layout_marginTop="20dp"
            android:layout_marginBottom="20dp"
            android:text="blank"
            android:textColor="@color/black"
            android:textSize="20sp"
            app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
            app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
            app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent" />

        <CheckBox
            android:id="@+id/groceryListCheckBox"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_marginTop="10dp"
            android:layout_marginEnd="15dp"
            android:text=""
            app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
            app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent" />
    </androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout>
</androidx.cardview.widget.CardView>
```

The app is just one recyclerview, with a textview and a checkbox for each item. What I'm trying to achieve is to save the state of the recyclerview on rotate. Basically when I check certain items I want them to still be checked when the device changes orientation.

I've tried many ways online, to save the instance or to use ondestroy/onpause but none of them seems to work anymore. Would like to know what I can do.

Comment: Your data set (`groceryList`) needs to store a boolean for whether a given item is checked, and `onBindViewHolder()` needs to set the checkbox based on that.

Comment: Thanks! Will try it and let you know.

Answer (score 0):

Create a model(data class) that has string and boolean. change the boolean on click of check box and on onBindViewHolder, check the state of the boolean and set that state to the checkbox. when the the checkbox is checked/unchecked change the value in the model and call notify data set changed. when you need to get the checked items, iterate the list and get the items where the boolean is true.